# How can i create a selectbox or checkbox in Drupal Webform?

Tags: drupal, drupal-webform

i can't create checkboxes or select boxes in drupal with webform

http://img151.imageshack.us/i/screengh.jpg/
http://img573.imageshack.us/i/screen2o.jpg/

so where are the options to create values of a select box?

thx

Answer (score 3):

1. Select the select options form field
2. Type in options in the format `key|value`
3. Check listbox / Check multiple
4. Result selectbox / Result checkboxes.

[image http://grab.by/grabs/47e886f18745cca9e810c9b72e35844d.png](http://grab.by/grabs/47e886f18745cca9e810c9b72e35844d.png)

Comment: @Huzur: You must have a module enable which is causing the problem. It has nothing with webforms to do.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is a CCK question.

Some field types have a "Select" as a option as well as "Checkboxes/Radio". If you select that, it will be what you want. You set default values and allowed values for the field on the configuration page.